# Not Understanding Jquery Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-hover

I have looked around and basically lived on the Jquery API page, but I can't seem to understand how to get a certain hover event to fire.

What I have:

```
<div class="profile profile-inner">
<div class="profile-footer">
<ul class="profile-actions">
```

What I want:

The ul class is hidden.  Then once the div class "profile profile-inner" is hovered I want the ul class to be visible.

Notes:

As far as I know, I will have to use `this` because there are many div classes `profile profile-inner` (because of many different members' profiles on that particular page)

Comment: Why are you adding same class twice?

Comment: Edited: Sorry about that.  It was meant to be profile profile-inner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes two arguments: a function to call when transitioning to the "hover state", and another function to call when leaving the "hover state":

```
$('.profile.profile-inner').find('ul').hide();
$('.profile.profile-inner').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').show();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul').hide();
});
```

I don't recommend doing this: Depending on the layout of your page, detecting hover with Javascript may be unreliable, and you may get "stuck" in a state. This can annoy users, and fortunately, you can use CSS by itself to do what you want:

```
.profile.profile-inner ul { display: none; }
.profile.profile-inner:hover ul { display: block; }
```

If your outer element is an `<a>` tag, this will even work in MSIE6.

If you want further backwards-compatibility, I recommend creating a [behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018.aspx)-shim to complement the CSS-based method instead of using jQuery's hover. This method works all the way back to MSIE4.

Comment: Uhm, `jQuery().hover()` is compatible with all browsers of relevant market share, including IE6 and possibly 5 as well.

Comment: @Christian - Sometimes the underlying mouseover/mouseout events get missed, especially near the edges of the window. This can cause the Javascript-based hover functionality to get stuck in a way that the CSS-based approach will not.

Comment: @geocar Thank you for your prompt reply and editing the initial answer as well to fit my mistake.  I will try this out as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript (or jQuery) for this, just use css:

```
profile-inner:hover .profile-actions{ display:block; }
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s997f/9/)

Comment: Thanks for the live demo and explanation.  Great site, I will need to bookmark that!